# How Can I Detect a Line in an Image For My Android App

Tags: android, image, camera, line

I want my Android app to take a photo and then analyze the image to locate the four outside corners of a square grid. I have looked at Hough transforms and they may be the way to go but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is an already-established line detection process. I am hoping to get something akin to QR bar code readers that watch the camera and then snap the photo when they recognize a QR pattern.
[edit] Want to have app capture image once a square grid (NOT a QR bar code) is detected. Sorry, should have stated question more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of Android QR Libs yout there. If that does not suffice for you I'd code it myself.